# Linq query returns null. Can't figure out why

Tags: linq

My result returns null.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> result = ( from r in db.vedhaeftedeFilers.AsEnumerable() where r.beskedId == id select new { r.filnavn, r.filtype, r.data })as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
```

there are data in the database, and the id are correct. I am guessing that it has
something to do with my use of IEnumerable, but cant figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator will return `null` if the object you are passing is not actually an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which it obviously is not because you are projecting into an anonymous type with `select new { ... }`.

As an aside, the `AsEnumerable()` call will ruin your performance by making your database table behave like a dumb array.

What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: im trying to pass my result into a datatable

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select new { r.filnavn, r.filtype, r.data }
> ```

That creates an anonymous type with read only properties `filnavn`, `filtype` and `data`. Thus the type of the LINQ comprehension expression (`from` ... `select`) is `IEnumerable<anonymous>`.

This type does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, so as [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504837/67392) notes, it will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

`select new { r.filnavn, r.filtype, r.data }`

...you are returning a collection of an anonymous type.  This is a problem because you're trying to cast this collection to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  Since you're using `as` to cast, it's "dying silently" and returning null since casting with the `as` keyword doesn't throw an InvalidCastException if the cast fails (as opposed to casting with parethesis like `MyClass x = (MyClass)MyObj`).

Try this instead:

`var result = ( from r in db.vedhaeftedeFilers.AsEnumerable() where r.beskedId == id select new { r.filnavn, r.filtype, r.data });`

Notice I used `var` and didn't attempt to cast the result to a type.